# execute an application from DELPHI code, FMX framework issue

Tags: delphi

How to run applcation is  widly described , one nice source  [code by Zarko Gajic](https://www.thoughtco.com/execute-and-run-applications-1058462)
We use a modified version like this working perfect under Windows and VCL framework

```
var
  ExitCode : DWORD;
  SEInfo : TShellExecuteInfo;
begin
  ///
  ///  Execute shell function from Delphi Code 
  ///
  FillChar(SEInfo, SizeOf(SEInfo), 0);
  SEInfo.cbSize := SizeOf(TShellExecuteInfo);
  WITH SEInfo DO
  begin
    fMask := SEE_MASK_NOCLOSEPROCESS;
    Wnd := OurClass.Handle;
    lpFile := PWidechar(EXENAMESTR);
    lpParameters := PWidechar(ParameterFile);
    nShow := SW_SHOWNORMAL;
  end;
  ///
  ///  Follow up our process 
  /// 
  if ShellexecuteEx(@SEInfo) then
  begin
    repeat
      GetExitCodeProcess(SEInfo.hProcess, ExitCode);
    until (ExitCode <> STILL_ACTIVE) OR Application.Terminated;
  end;
```

Question: we can't compile this  code  in an FMX framework application as Wnd := OurClass.Handle; fails, Handle is not defined, how to solve this problem ?
Best solution is a code working for both Frameworks  VCL&FMX .

Comment: Note that `Wnd` is optional.

Comment: As a side note, you should put a sleep in your loop to avoid eating all the CPU (or, even better, use [`WaitForSingleObject()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/synchapi/nf-synchapi-waitforsingleobject)).

Comment: What object/type is `OurClass` exactly? Only FMX Forms have a `Handle`, child controls do not. And even then, the `Handle` is not a Win32 `HWND`, like in VCL You can use `FMX.Platform.Win.FormToHWND()` to get the actual `HWND`

Answer (score 0):

This is for Windows only.  You don't need to specify a Windows Handle to launch a program, so you can safely pass 0 (or nil if it complains).

As I recall this is used to ensure that the new program's main window will be positioned above the invoking program's main window in the z-order (so it's visible).

Alternatively you can use the Windows SDK CreateProcess call instead.